# Как обработать большой тензор numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Имеется тензор, сохранённый в файле `.npy`, который читаю так:

```
x = np.load('x.npy')
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выполнить с ним математические преобразования и сохранить в другой файл.

```
x = process(x)
np.save('x_processed.npy', x)
```

Исходный тензор помещается в оперативную память, возвращаемое функцией `process` значение - нет.

Можно преобразовывать данные по частям: применять функцию `process` к срезу тензора `x`, но формат `.npy` не поддерживает добавление (append).

Я попробовал применить `numpy.memmap` таким образом:

```
x = np.load('x.npy', mmap_mode='r+')
```

Ожидаемое поведение - тензор не будет загружен в оперативную память, вместо этого будет создано отображение файла в оперативную память. Если в дальнейшем редактировать данные в тензоре `x`, то они будут редактироваться именно в файле.

Но функция `process` построена именно так, что она возвращает вновь созданный тензор, поэтому он создаётся в оперативной памяти и полностью её съедает.

Всё-таки есть какой-то способ обрабатывать исходный тензор по частям (срезам)?

---

Пусть имеются два файла, полученные путём обработки среза функцией `process`, которые затем загружаются посредством `mmap`:

```
x1 = np.load('x1.npy', mmap_mode='r')
x2 = np.load('x2.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

И файл, куда надо записать результат:

```
x_targ = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=full_tensor_shape)
```

тогда можно ли делать так:

```
x_targ[0:x1.shape[0], :, :, :] = x1
x_targ[0:x2.shape[0], :, :, :] = x2
```

Или как их объединить в один файл?

Comment: Математика функции `process` позволяет обрабатывать тензор по частям?

Comment: Без знания что происходит в `process` все рассуждения бессмысленны. Навскидку могу предположить, что на входе у вас разреженная матрица, а на выходе обычная. Но это лишь предположение. В этом случае можно постараться переделать преобразования так, чтобы оставаться в поле разреженных матриц в процессе вычислений.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, На вход функции `process` можно подать срез, например, такой: `process(x[1000:5000, :, :, :])`. Он обработается корректно. Я правильно понял ваш вопрос?

Comment: Тогда загрузите исходный тензор, разрежьте его на части, части сохраните в отдельные файлы. Загружайте части по одной, обрабатывайте, результаты сохраняйте в отдельные файлы. Откройте финальный тензор для результата в виде mmap, загружайте обработанные части по одной, записывайте в нужную область финального тензора. Как-то так. Часть шагов можно объединить (экономя на файловых операциях) если память позволяет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, функция `process` содержит операции изменения вложенных размерностей, изменения типа данных, математические преобразования полученных записей. Каждая операция выполняется библиотечной функцией с аналогичной сигнатурой (например, `keras.applications.inception_v3.preprocess_input`).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, см. обновление. Сейчас нет рабочего ПК, проверить только завтра смогу, поэтому глупые вопросы задаю.

Comment: Вы уже всё расписали как надо. Осталось протестировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку размер выходного тензора известен, можно создать сразу весь целевой файл, содержащий новый тензор, и открыть его как отображение в память. Затем читать исходный файл по частям, обрабатывать его и записывать результат в целевой.

```
x = np.load('x.npy', mmap_mode='r')
x_out_shape = (x.shape[0], A, B, C)
x_out = np.memmap('x_out.npy', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=x_out_shape)
particle = 1000

filePos = 0
while True:
    # Если filePos + particle больше размера тензора, 
    # то будет использоваться верхняя граница
    x_out[filePos:filePos + particle, :, :, :] = process(x[filePos:filePos + particle, :, :, :])
    filePos += particle
    if filePos >= x_out_shape[0]:
        break
x_out.flush()
```